# League of Legends (again) and "opinion based" questions

Tags: discussion, closing

Just found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294308/which-champion-is-stronger-in-the-meta-in-this-current-meta) that I answered earlier was closed because it's opinion based.

It's regarding what Champion is currently strong. The question makes sense because LoL is a game that is updated every two weeks, often changing completly the dynamics of the game. At the End of the Competitive Season a set of changes were put foward which made 3 sets of characters **extremely strong**, and both in theory and factually they are miles away from other champions (as confirmed by the winrates and change in average score).

The question was put on hold because it's opinion based, yet there are several data sources to be based on a non-opinionated answer. Why are LoL questions constantly being closed for the same reason, yet that reason being completly invalid?

Yes, which is "stronger" is usually a bad question on most games:

- In Tekken is Kazuya stronger than Jin or Heihachi? It depends on the player, because the combos change, but their inherent power doesn't.
- In Crusader Kings is a high martial ruler better than a high intrigue ruler? It depends on whether you want your military to be really strong, or you want the ability to murder people and get away with it.
- In Football Manager is Ronaldo better than Messi? It depends on your tactic and the role you want to put them in.

However in **League of Legends**, that relativity is really only there if we're not talking about 1v1 laning phase scenarios, like the toplane mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/league-of-legends-questions-separating-opinion-from-meta-strategy-and-other-f

Comment: You might want to take a look at who wrote the most voted reply on that one  (albeit, only answer) ^

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7619/why-has-this-question-not-been-closed

Comment: Another problem being that these questions are out of date 2 weeks later because Rito cannot make up their mind about things and constantly change *everything* - These questions basically become useless after being asked and don't help anyone else looking for the same thing later on.

Comment: @Oak - I noticed when linked.  The point being specifically the "Who is stronger, x or y?" section in your answer.  This entire scenario seems to contradict that statement.

Comment: @camelCase It looks like that, but I disagree, the OP refered to "toplane", which is a select number of characters (about 10-12, with only 4-5 being regularly featured every patch)

Comment: @Oak - Yes, it does but it simply asks how to choose between 2 named characters in toplane, which effectively is "Who is stronger, x or y?" - scoped to the toplane.

Answer (score 11):

The question was basically asking for a recommendation of which champions to play. It's not useful to future visitors of the site, especially because any given answer could very well be invalidated in as little as a month. This is the biggest problem with LoL questions - a lot of them focus on *the current meta*, which by definition is already open to interpretation.

Additionally, you quote "high Elo" statistics as a reference... the problem with that is "high Elo" (Platinum and above) accounts for [approximately 10%](http://www.leagueofgraphs.com/rankings/rank-distribution) of the total solo-queue player base. The other 90% (especially those in Bronze and Silver) shouldn't care *as much* about the meta, because due to their lack of skill (compared to higher Elo players), almost any champs can feasibly work.

Questions about League that focus on overarching game concepts that are unlikely to change (for example, ["What do these abbreviations mean?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/32299/145980), ["How cost effective is recall?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24833/145980), or ["What's the difference between top and bottom lane?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/25258/145980)) are good questions, in my opinion. Questions that are limited to whatever the "current meta" is at the time are not good questions. There are plenty of other places to go to discuss current power trends - the League of Legends [subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends) or even the "summoner school" [subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool) work well for this in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

The question shouldn't have been closed as primarily opinion based but I don't think that it should be reopened in it's current state.

The main problem I see with this question is it being basically "Too localized" (Yes I know we don't have this close reason anymore) since it would require too many updates due to the amount of patches and changes done by Riot games.

Here are some question titles that would be perfectly fine for our site without being too broad, primarily opinion based or too localized.

**How can I find out whether a champion is viable or not?**

**Which champions are strong in a Tank meta?**

**Which champions excel at doing this Job?**

All of these are answerable by someone who knows the game well.

Questions about the viability of characters, items and strategies in competitive games are on topic on this site and fall under the category of good subjective question. Obviously these questions do get closed sometimes since it's kinda hard to differentiate between good and bad subjective questions but **that's what the reopen button is there for**.

Comment: The problem with "Which champions are strong in [insert] meta?" is that it depends on why that meta came about in the first place. For example, at the start of last season Assassins were extremely strong. That's because ADCs were really strong and assassins could easily take them out. Once ADCs were nerfed, assassins building tank items was the new meta, because not only ADCs were weak, but also because Tanks were weak (but the items were not). However other times it's because Tanks get really good changes (like with Colossus), and become ridiculously strong due to that. Same issue arises.

Comment: @Oak Usually the reason why the meta changes isn't too much of an issue in league. If there's a tank meta ADCs will always be strong. If there's an ADC Meta assassins will also always be strong. The meta constantly changes and sort of "rotates". If there's a meta where assassins build tanky it's no longer a Tank or Assassin meta but more of a bruiserish meta. Strong champions are either those who are the strongest in their current meta role or the ones that counter the current meta role by being one step ahead of the change cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I didn't think it was very opinion-based.

Sure, a lot of it depends on player-skill, but if we factor out player skill and instead focus on the tier list on which is the stronger top laner by considering all the meta pairings, then the answer is pretty clear.

Answer (score -2):

I can't see why this is considered opinion-based.

Ideally this should be split into 2 questions (one for Gnar vs. Jayce and one for Graves vs. Lee Sin) and perhaps scoped to the current season.  Regardless, it is answerable by someone with experience in the game.

I can't provide an answer for this question specifically, but if this was in a game I have lost many hours then I could easily provide reasons to help choose between 2 characters.

Asking which is stronger between x or y in any game isn't really a bad question.  It is something a real gamer would likely ask.  It is the kind of question an expert in the game can answer by providing experiences, statistics etc.  The answers will likely help the original asker, and hopefully future visitors.  These types of questions seem to fit well within the scope of **[Gameplay strategies and tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

These types of questions are not good for someone who wants to answer but is relying on google alone.  The only off-topic reason for any of these questions would probably be the too broad reason.  I wouldn't say that was the case for the LoL question linked (other than splitting into 2 questions), but something like the Ronaldo vs. Messi one would need some more context (which team, league, season etc).

Part of the problem here may be that some people just vote to close as opinion-based as soon as they see "best" or "better" in a question.

These types of questions are not being asked to poll for a personal favourite.  They are being asked to justify the selection between choices.  They will require an explanation for how/why a choice is made.